# Arduino Serial.read(), reading wrong decimal number that corresponds to ASCII character

Tags: arduino, ascii

I am writing arduino sketch that will do certian things when certian characters are given through serial port!

important part of my arduino sketch is this:

```
while(Serial.available()){
Status = Serial.read();
Serial.println(Status);

if (Status == A){
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Pin 13 -> ON");

  }else if(Status == B){
      digitalWrite(led, LOW);
      Serial.println("Pin 13 -> OFF");
    }
}
```

BTW: variable *Status* is integer type!!

Problem is that it sometimes works and sometimes does not, so when I upload sketch it works fine I type letter A and it is converted to number 65, type letter B and it is converted to number 66. And after some time it suddenly starts outputing number 193 and 194. It would be ok if it return 193 and 194 alwas but it does not! 
    Hope somone will know the solution and if you want more info...

Answer (score 0):

`if (Status == A)` is comparing two variables `Status` and `A`.

You should replace it with `if (Status == 'A')`.
Same with `if (Status == 'B')`.

Comment: no because numbers are assigned to this variables A = 65 and B = 66,
serial read is converted to integer ! When you  send character A in serial monitor it is recognised as number 65.

Comment: But this is a quite strange way of handling received data. You have one variable for each possible received character? Why not receiving and handling them as chars?   Can we see where you declare the variables A,b,...? As @mhopeng notices you have the MSB enabled. This can happen if you mix `unsigned` with `signed` `short ints`

Answer (score 0):

Well, 193/194 are only different from 65/66 by 1 bit (the MSB). You could mask the leftmost bit like so:

```
Status = Status & 01111111; // MSB will be zeroed
```

or with a double shift:

```
Status = Status << 1;
Status = Status >> 1; // now you have dropped the leftmost bit
```

See the docs [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BitMask)